# Unable to set "always open with" checkbox

Tags: windows-8, firefox, file-association

Configuration:

- windows 8 (desktop)
- firefox (latest version)

I've been trying to figure out how to enable the checkbox to "always open with ... application for file type", for quite a while without any luck.

[image]

Can anybody explain to me how I can enable the checkbox (see red rectangle). It's in Dutch, but I hope you recognize the dialog.

Tried so far:
- default programs (control panel)
- HKCU/Microsoft/.../FileExts: remove the UserChoice (but it was already removed, so no luck there either)

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be easily possible. It is likely the [Content-Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header#Responses) of the .torrent file at the site/server is set as a generic **application/octet-stream** [MIME media type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_application) i.e. binary data that can be anything including .exe, .msi etc. So if Firefox were to enable that option then any subsequent files with the application/octet-stream MIME media type including programs, installers etc. would open in uTorrent which would be in the least undesirable. The correct MIME media type for .torrent seems to be [application/x-bittorrent](http://filext.com/file-extension/TORRENT) though it isn't officially listed [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types).

In Firefox, browse to the site, open **Tools** (Alt + T) > **Web Developer** > [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console), **Clear** any current entries in the opened Web Console, and click on the download link for the .torrent file. Next, in the Web Console click on the GET link corresponding to the .torrent and look for the **Content-Type** under **Response Headers**.

[Firefox Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)

[Properly Configuring Server MIME Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Properly_Configuring_Server_MIME_Types)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help, will try what you propose this evening!

Comment: No problem :) Please note that if the Content-Type shows application/octet-stream, then it may not be possible at all, unless perhaps a Firefox extension is used.

Comment: Aye, you were right all along :). content type indeed is application/octet-stream. So maybe a different torrent site would solve this problem for me?

Comment: Yeah, found another site already. Hah! Thx a lot, this have been annoying me for quite some time now :).